# INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE statement in DATA WAREHOUSE

Tags: data-warehouse

Simple question:
Can I use INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE statement in dealing with DATA WAREHOUSE? Or there is special techniques to use it with DATA WAREHOUSE?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually Data Warehouses are just normal SQL databases. You can use whatever techniques and technologies you want to work with Data Warehouses.

Comment: Thanks. I were worry and want to be sure before go deeply.

Comment: Just remeber to follow good guidelines when you design one: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902672(v=sql.80).aspx and you are good to go!